# Find the minimum p: for q > p cubic $ x^3 -7x^2 + qx + 16 =0 $ has only one real root using algebraic arguements only

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Hi this question can be easily solve with turning point arguement used in differential calculus, I'm curious how to solve it in an algebraic way i.e. using only algebraic arguments in the proof and avoid calculus and or powerful theorems relying on analysis.

So far I used Vieta's relation and some plug n' chug to arrive at:

$ q > \frac{49}{4}$

The correct answer is p = 8 i.e. $q > 8$

Comment: Is using the discriminant of cubic polynomial allowed

Comment: I don't understand, what does $p$ signify? What is wrong with $p=7$?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore You can submit it as an answer if you want, I'm afraid it's very hard for many to  remember cubic discriminant in an exam. It would be more appreciable if you can construct an algebraic argument which can be arrived by someone in 15 minutes(you are allotted 15 min for proof based questions)

Comment: @LightYagamip is the minimum value such that q > p ensures the cubic has only 1 real root at p =7 that is q > 7 for the case 7<q<8 more than one real root exist for this cubic

Comment: Oh, all right. That is a fancy way of saying it. You could've just said, find the minimum value of $q$ so that only one real root exists. why introduce another variable?

Answer (score 4):

If $q=8$ then $(x-4)^2(x+1)=0$ has three roots so $p\ge 8$. Now consider $q>8$ and suppose there is more than 1 real root. Then all three (counting multiplicity) roots are real and, by Vieta, their product is $-16$.

However the equation can be written as $$(x-4)^2(x+1)=(8-q)x.$$

The cubic $y=(x-4)^2(x+1)$ has no points in the fourth quadrant and only has points in the second quadrant for $-1\le x\le0$. However, $y=(8-q)x$ only has points in the second and fourth quadrants.

Therefore all three roots satisfy  $-1\le x\le0$ and so the product of the roots has magnitude at most $1$, a contradiction.

Therefore $p=8$.

Comment: +1 although it is motivated by the knowing  result $q>8$

Comment: Hi how did you discover setting q =8 to be begin with? You could have chosen any q such that cubic is factorisable(Kudos to your factorization skillsto spot a neat factorisation when q = 8 )
Also I didn't understand how you wrote cubic in form of (8-q)x.Kindly elaborate?

Comment: I tried $8$ because you had said $8$ was the answer! Otherwise I would have used calculus to get it.

Comment: Your answer is proof provided I give question as : Let p =8 and I ask the person to prove for q >8 the cubic will have only one real root, completely opposite to what it was asked in the original question, that is, **to discover** p=8

Comment: Re rewriting the cubic just add $8-qx$ to each side.

Comment: On the contrary the answer is a proof that p=8 irrespective of how the question was asked because all that is necessary is to prove that p<8 does not work and prove that p=8 does work. A proof is a proof irrespective of how a person thought of it.

Answer (score 3):

For guessing the answer $q=8$: just try to find the borderline case, i.e. one simple root and a repeated root. Say $a$ is the simple root and $u$ is the repeated one.

Using Vieta, it boils down to $a+2u=7, au^2=-16$. Hence $2u^3-7u^2-16=0$. Test roots using rational root theorem, and we find $(u-4)(2u^2+u+4)=0$. The only solution is $u=4$, giving $q=8$.